# I want to change Button.Content as soon as I click on the button. This change is done when execution of Button_Click function is completed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have Button_Click function which processes a huge amount of Excel data and takes around 1 minute. I want to change the **button.content** as soon as I click on the button. But this waits for the function to execute completely and then text is changed.

```
private void LoadData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//Change button content after this line

//This code will take time to execute

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting the Content property you may run and await an async Task. You may also want to disable the Button as long as the long-running operation is in progress.

```
private async void LoadData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    button.Content = "Loading Data...";
    button.IsEnabled = false;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // perform the long-running operation here
    });

    button.Content = "Load Data"; // optionally, reset the Content
    button.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the solution but I am trying this and still wpf is behaving same. It is changing the button text quickly after long running task is done and again reverting it.